# I am getting thjis error" A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing ..." after I have reistalled the SQL server and VS

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have formatted my PC. I have reinstalled Microsoft SQL Server and Visual Studio. I have pulled my code and database from Github and I wanted to continue my work.(I have started a project with using EF code-first)

Although I have enabled the TCP connection I am getting this error "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The remote computer refused the network connection.)"

It is strange because, if I am starting a new application (using EF code-first) it works. It is connecting to the database without any issues and fetching the data.

My guess is that the name of the SQL instance is not the same. However, I don't have any connection string nor SQL instance name on my app.config files. Not sure if this is the problem though. I have tried anything that I found on related questions.

Anyone know what would be the problem (and the fix)?
To recap:
 - I have reinstalled SQL Server and Visual Studio
 - if I create a new C# app, it connects to the saved database which was attached to the new instance
 - I cannot connect to the database in question from my old app. I am getting the exception above.

Much appreciated your help,
Liviu

UPDATE: the correscponding app.config is bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you check the connection string in web config file

Comment: the DAL is on a calss library, the coresponding app.config is:
/...
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
..

Comment: can you share the app.config code here so I can look at that what is the issue

Comment: I ahve put it on the question, please see the ipdate.

Comment: I think connection string is missing

Comment: I never had any connection string on any .config file and it worked. I am using EF 6.1.4.

Comment: yes, you're right. if we use entity framework it will be generated automatically when we build the apps but sometimes it will not happen

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <entityFramework>    
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I have removed defaultConnectionFactory in app config file